# How fragile are Minor Conjurations?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, summoning

The School of Conjuration grants a Wizard the *Minor Conjuration* feature:

> [...] you can use your action to conjure up an inanimate object
>   in your hand or on the ground in an unoccupied space that you can see within 10 feet of you. This object can be no larger than 3 feet on a side and weigh no more than 10 pounds, and its form must be that of a nonmagical object that you have seen.
>
> The object disappears after 1 hour, when you use this feature again, or **if it takes any damage**.

Under which of the following conditions will damage cause a conjured item to disappear, rendering it useless?

1. Attacking with a conjured weapon?
2. Firing a conjured piece of ammunition?
3. Being attacked while wearing conjured leather armor?
4. Being attacked while holding a conjured shield?
5. Restraining a creature using conjured manacles?
6. Consuming conjured food or drink?
7. Conjuring a lit torch?

Answer (score 7):

I would go so far as to say "only when it loses a hit point".

With regards to arrows, I could see the temptation to make them go away, but I think RAW, they get recovered at a rate of 50% just like a regular arrow.

All of your examples make sense from a literal interpretation of damage, but not a game definition. Damage has a magnitude, and a type. Wear and tear aren't hit points. (Your characters cells are dying all the time, but it's not damage)

Comment: Even though this question has been closed as a duplicate, it's worth clarifying in case anyone comes across this Q&A in the future - condition #1 does cause the conjured object to disappear if it deals any damage, as of the [2017 PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The rules don't say so it's time to make a ruling.

To guide you start with the definition of damage: 
physical harm that impairs the **value, usefulness, or normal function** of something.

My judgement FWIW:

1. Attacking with a conjured weapon? Normal function - OK
2. Firing a conjured piece of ammunition? Normal function - OK; 50% chance it is then damaged
3. Being attacked while wearing conjured leather armor? Normal function - OK
4. Being attacked while holding a conjured shield? Normal function - OK
5. Restraining a creature using conjured manacles? Normal function - OK, unless the creature breaks them
6. Consuming conjured food or drink? Normal function - OK, but you'll be hungry in an hour: might as well conjure Chinese food then
7. Conjuring a lit torch? Normal function - OK

Comment: No I mean, it's fine - no damage, will clarify

Comment: Even though this question has been closed as a duplicate, it's worth clarifying in case anyone comes across this Q&A in the future - condition #1 does cause the conjured object to disappear if it deals any damage, as of the [2017 PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of that condition is that if the object is targeted and hit, it is destroyed immediately. Also, if the object falls more than 10 feet, it takes damage and gets destroyed.

That is, none of the conditions you described would cause the object to take damage unless specifically targeted.

Comment: Even though this question has been closed as a duplicate, it's worth clarifying in case anyone comes across this Q&A in the future - condition #1 does cause the conjured object to disappear if it deals any damage, as of the [2017 PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf).